# Set the default Control Template of a Custom Control without using a Style

Tags: .net, wpf, custom-controls, desktop-application

I'm looking for a way to more strongly bind the default `Control Template` of my custom control to the control instead of using a `Style`. I'll show my simplest example here to explain the need:

```
    public class UnitTextBox : TextBox
    {
        public string UnitLabel {...}
        public static readonly DependencyProperty UnitLabelProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("UnitLabel", typeof(string), typeof(UnitTextBox), new PropertyMetadata(""));
    }
```

This control just adds an extra string property for a unit label (like millimeters), given the following  simple control template derived from `TextBox`, it puts a unit label within the text box to keep things nice and clean and properly dimensioned:

```
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="UnitTextBoxTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type local:UnitTextBox}">
        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <DockPanel>
                <TextBlock DockPanel.Dock="Right" Text="{TemplateBinding UnitLabel}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="8,0,2,0" Focusable="False" IsHitTestVisible="False" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                            FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}"   />
                <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" Focusable="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"/>
            </DockPanel>
        </Border>
...(triggers)
    </ControlTemplate>
```

All of that works wonderfully, however this control is basically still a `TextBox`, and I have lots of styles for TextBoxes already that I use, so I don't want to use a default style to apply the template:

```
    <Style  TargetType="{x:Type local:UnitTextBox}">
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource UnitTextBoxTemplate}"/>
    </Style>
```

Doing the above means that I can't use my `RegularTextBox` style which works just fine for my `UnitTextBox`. So instead, every time I wish to add a `UnitTextBox` I must explicitly specify the template that makes it function properly:

```
  <ctrl:UnitTextBox Template="{DynamicResource UnitTextBoxTemplate}" UnitLabel="mm/min" 
                    Style="{StaticResource RegularTextBox}"/>
```

I've been working with WPF for ages, but I do relatively few custom controls, and have suffered with they Default Style method when I do, but I'm thinking there *must* be a better way, but google-fu has failed me time and again.

I'm hoping there is some way to assign the template in the constructor/Init routine of `UnitTextBox`, but I'm struggling to reach the resource dictionary from code; so I'm wondering if there's a more esoteric way to do this.

Comment: Can't you simply base the default style on the existing style and just set the `Template` property?  `<Style  TargetType="{x:Type local:UnitTextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource RegularTextBox}">...</Style>`. What's the problem with this approach?

Comment: You can, but then you have to multiply the number of TextBox styles you have by the number of TextBox derivatives. Which I expect will yield a mess in short order since I have a few other similar cases. That's my grudging solution, but it seems there should be something elegant, right?

Comment: I don't think I understand the issue. If you want another style than the default one, just set the `Style` property of that particular element. *"I'm hoping there is some way to assign the template in the constructor/Init routine of UnitTextBox"*. How would this help?

Comment: The core function of the UnitTextBox control (adding a TextBlock inside a TextBox) is bound up in the default style, if I have 5 different TextBox styles, using these styles on the UnitTextBox works fine, except it overrides the default style, which provides the template. So I have to explicitly assign the template, or I have to create a style based on each of the 5 styles, add a setter for Template and use that. It works, but it sucks. Setting a template in the init means it has the Template already assigned if the style fails to do so.

Comment: You may handle the `Loaded` and set the `Template` property in the event handler.

Comment: @mm8 That works, if you'd like to post it as an answer I'll gladly mark it. I tried this.FindResource("UnitTextBoxTemplate") in the constructor and EndInit, but there were no resources loaded yet, doing same from Loaded handler does the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to define a default `Style`, you may handle the `Loaded` event in your control class and set the `Template` property in the event handler.

```
public UnitTextBox() : base()
{
    this.Loaded += UnitTextBox_Loaded;
}

private void UnitTextBox_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var res = this.FindResource("UnitTextBoxTemplate");
    this.Template = res as ControlTemplate;
}
```